# Can we make results of MySQL select query editable and sortable?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select query which pulls up data from a table and displays it accordingly

```
$display_query= "select * from customer WHERE abc_mailing_list = '$abc' AND def_mailing_list ='$def' AND ghi_mailing_list = '$ghi' AND position_category IN($var) AND country_code='$country_cat' ORDER BY state";

$display_result=mysqli_query($dbc2,$display_query); 

<table width = "100%"border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<tr style="background-color: #51626F; color: #FFFFFF;">
<th> S.No</th>
<th> First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Position Category</th>
<th>State</th>
<th>Country</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Agency</th>
<th>Department</th>

</tr>
<?php
$colour2 = "transparent";  
$colour1 = "#B1B0A7";  
$count = 0;
$row_count = 0; 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($display_result)){

$rowcolor = ($row_count % 2) ? $colour1 : $colour2;
$count++;
?>
<tr style="background: <? echo $rowcolor; ?>;">
<td width="10%" height="20"><? echo $count; ?></td>
<td width="10%" height="20"><? echo $row['first_name']; ?></td>
<td width="10%" height="20"><? echo $row['last_name']; ?></td>
<td width="10%" height="20"><? echo $row['position_category']; ?></td>
<td width="10%" height="20"><? echo $row['state']; ?></td>
<td width="10%" height="20"><? echo $row['country_code']; ?></td>
<td width="10%" height="20"><? echo $row['title']; ?></td>
<td width="10%" height="20"><? echo $row['agency']; ?></td>
<td width="10%" height="20"><? echo $row['department']; ?></td>

</tr>
<?
$row_count++;
}
?>
```

My question is I want to make everything editable so that if the user finds some mistake in the returned results, he should have the option to edit then and there and save it, so that it can be saved in the database. Is there any plugin for this? I'm sorry if this is a trivial question, I'm new to PHP. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some understanding about how this works. What you do now is show the data in a web page. You need to implement a mechanism to update the database back, this is not going to happen instantly, you need to show the data in an editable format like a textbox and than let the user change it and click an update button for example when he is done. then you need to respond to a click on that button, take the edited data from the textbox and update the right location in the database. that is simply put and can be done in many different ways. start doing something and post some code so we could help :)

Comment: Thank you, editing and sorting is very easy in MS access, I thought there is some mechanism for that. Now I understand :)

Comment: you welcome. MS access is a program made for that, meaning someone (A microsoft programmer) has already coded that functionality there. But here its a whole new world and you need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The edit part would take some work, but you could use DataTables (a JQuery plugin) to handle the sorting, searching etc..

DataTables (table plug-in for jQuery)
www.datatables.net

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I never knew about DataTables, will look into that

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
'<td width="10%" height="20"><? echo $count; ?></td>'
```

you should have this column be a unique auto-incrementing number from the database, so each row can be identified. from there, you can use forms(either checkboxes to select which colums need to be edited, or text inputs that can be edited on each column). if you choose to use checkboxes and a 'edit' button, have a hidden input with the unique id attached. Then check if

```
(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['firstName']))
{
    $firstName = sanitizeStrin($_POST['firstName']);
    $id = sanitizeString($_POST['id']);
  mysql_query( "UPDATE table SET first_name = '$firstName' WHERE uniqueID='$id'" );
}
```

.. ect to see which column in which row needs to be updated. A lot of code is needed to check every column, but you get the idea. Hope this helps.